# How to conditionally render routes with react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router-dom

How do I set up conditional routes with exclusive Components in React?
I want the upload route to be exclusive to when authenticated, which is set in ComponentdDidMount.

```
  render = () => {
    let routes = (
      <Switch>
        <Route path = "/" exact render = {() => <Home />
        <Route path = "/video" render = {() => <Video />} />
        <Route path = "/upload" exact render = {() => <Upload />} />
        <Redirect to = "/foo"/>
      </Switch>
    )
    if(this.props.isAuthenticated){
      routes = (
        <Switch>
          <Route path = "/" exact render = {() => <Dashboard />} />
          <Route path = "/upload`" render = {() => <Upload />} /> 
          <Route path = "/video" render = {() => <Video />} />
          <Route path = "/foo" render = {() => <h1>Foo</h1>} />
          <Redirect to = "/bar" />
        </Switch>
      )
    }
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Layout>
            {routes}
        </Layout>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Right it's using the first set of Route components to check the route, and if the route doesn't match I get redirected to '/foo' which then renders the h1. If I try to access 'upload', I believe it gets rendered for a split second, and then I end up with infinite redirects to '/bar'. '/video' does render the video component. Can someone provide some information as to what may be going wrong and how I can make sure only one set of Routes is being used?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just need to handle authentication on private routes, you can get more info [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow)

I had the same question a few months ago, and what I did is to create a wrapper to check if user has the necessary rights to see that item.

```
render: () => AuthorizeRoute(
      Amortizations, // Component to load
      'anyvalidRole4ex' // {string} constant
    ),
```

If you are using redux, could be something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import NotAllowed from './NotAllowed';

export default function HasPermissionWrapper(
  WrappedComponent,
  requiredRoles,
  FallbackComponent
) {
  class HasPermission extends React.PureComponent {
    static propTypes = {
      userRoles: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    };

    render() {
      const userRoles = this.props.userRoles.toJS();
      const hasPermission = userRoles
        .map(({roleId}) => requiredRoles.includes(roleId))
        .some((checks) => !!checks);

      if (!hasPermission) {
        if (FallbackComponent) {
          return <FallbackComponent />;
        }
        return <NotAllowed userRoles={userRoles} />;
      }

      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  }

  const mapStateToProps = ({auth}) => ({
    userRoles: auth.getIn(['user', 'roles']),
  });

  return connect(mapStateToProps)(HasPermission);
}
```